# Intercontinental internet connection partially slow

Tags: networking, router, vpn, rsync, tcp

I am currently staying in Asia. My home network and my office network are located in Europe.

When I use speedtest.net with a local server I get around 40Mbps up-/download. When I select a server close to the physical location of my networks in Europe I still get around 10-15 Mbps download and 3Mbps upload speed. When I use a browser to open a website from these networks I get the same good speed (video streaming is no problem).

But when I open a VPN connection to either one of these networks the speed drops dramatically - speedtest.net now shows 0.7Mbps download and 3.9Mbps upload speed (?!). Therefore video streaming with active VPN is barely an option.

Also when I use rsync (without VPN) the download speed is very slow (50Kpbs) but the upload is great (3+Mbps) - which makes no sense to me.

I never experienced these issues when using VPN / rsync in Europe so I am pretty sure that the routers or the encryption are not the problem. But I encountered it in several locations (different countries) around Asia so it seems to be no local issue.

Therefore I wonder - is there anyone capping the speed of certain connections like internet/rsync on purpose? Or is there a logical technical explanation for that (higher ping)? How can I investigate further or even solve this?

Comment: Without knowing the country and the provider you are using from Asia it is difficult to find someone able to answer you... Note: by default `rsync` uses default SSH port 22 to sync files over local to remote hosts and vice versa. Did you try to download a huge file via `scp` from your slow network without VPN? If slow try to download it through another port...

Comment: When you hit a Europe-based website without VPN, you might actually be loading all your page resources from a local (to Asia) CDN edge node. When you said video streaming was fine, it would be interesting to know exactly which IP address the stream was coming from, and whether that address was in Europe or Asia. When you hit the same site from a Europe-terminated VPN, you'd be streaming from Europe through your VPN tunnel.

Comment: My current provider is FPT Telecom from Vietnam. My current rsync connection uses port 5885 and I use rsync without VPN. The videos I usually stream come from the Swiss TV website (srf.ch) - I don't think they have another node in Asia.

Comment: To further verify what is exactly happening, try timing two different connections, **both** from your location to a server you control (always the same server and connection of course). In both cases you will transfer a large zip file at maximum compression: once through SSH with no protocol compression, once through HTTP (and maybe again through HTTPS). On any reasonably modern hardware, the speed *ought* to be roughly the same *unless* something is differentiating between encrypted and non-encrypted connections.

Comment: If you look at the initial handshake of a slow connection in Wireshark, is windows scaling enabled? With a high RTT time and with no windows scaling, that could cause a poor experience.

Comment: @HelpingHand I didn't install Wireshark so far. Is there another way I can check about Windows scaling? I use Win10 and I gues it's more or less on default settings.

Comment: PS: According to https://www.auvik.com/media/blog/tcp-window-size there is no need to make any manual adjustments; like I said I never changed any default settings in this area.

Comment: PS2: I also found https://www.duckware.com/blog/how-windows-is-killing-internet-download-speeds/index.html but the problem described there seems to be fixed in (my) Win10

Comment: The server or a piece of software on the client can affect how windows scaling is negotiated.  The only way for sure is to see a packet trace of the handshake of the connection with poor data transfer.

Comment: Tried what LSemi suggested. Here are the results: Prepared a 10mb zip on my server in my own network in Switzerland. Downloaded it through normal http from Vietnam - took about 5min (~350kbps avg). Opened a vpn to this network and downloaded again through http - same results. Then opened a vpn to my office network in Switzerland and downloaded again through http - now it took < 1min (~3mbps avg). From my understanding this does not prove what I said above but it shows that a faster speed IS possible and some configuration is wrong.

Comment: The main difference I can see is that with the office VPN the speed is constant and goes up to almost 5mbps max while without vpn or with my private vpn the speed drops every 1s to almost zero and leaves a very distorted graphical view (in the wlan performance task manager section). What settings could be changed when opening the office vpn?

Answer (score 0):

For the records: I tried many things including most of the suggestions mentioned here: https://www.speedguide.net/analyzer.php (especially the optimizer tool). With absolutely no impact.

But I can do two tests with speedtest.net, one time connecting to "Lausanne (Swiss Network)" and one time to "Schoenenwerd" which are both located in Switzerland. Lausanne has 16/2 and Schoenenwerd has 0.6/4 (!!).

So my conclusion is that it depends on how one gets connected. I have no idea if there is any way to influence that but I'm pretty sure it is not related to my machine. Explanations or suggestions still welcome.